# Export compressed videos from quicktime screencast / screenrecording

Tags: software-recommendation, video, screen-capture, quicktime

I create quite a few screencasts to show colleagues how to do more complex tasks and share bugs that i am finding.

For this I use the `File > Screenrecording` feature in quicktime.

Once im done recording i save the video to the relevant location, but the exported videos are often 20-30mb even for a relatively short one.

What i tend to do at the moment is then run these videos through Handbrake (open source video compressing software) which gets the videos down to a much more manageable (email-able) size, usually between 2-5mb.

The only issue with this is its another step, and involves opening other software letting it process etc.

Is there a built in export / compression tool in quicktime where i can export smaller videos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to export instead of save. You can go to File → Export → iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch & Apple TV...

Then pick an option.

[image]

iPod touch & iPhone 3GS is the one that give you the smaller file size with a resolution of 640×400.

For the screenshot I test it with a video of 6.9 MB.